# How do I check if the user has entered more than 1 decimal in a text field?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a tipCalculator app but if the user enters a number with multiple decimal points, the app crashes.  How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest stopping the user from entering more than one decimal point.

1. Add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your class declaration.
2. In your `viewDidLoad` method add the following line:

   ```
   yourTextField.delegate = self
   ```
3. Finally add the following method to your class:

   ```
   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
       return textField.text?.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count <= 2
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be just testing the amount of decimals in the text string, and if there are more than 1, alert the user.

```
NSUInteger numOfDecimals = [[yourTextField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] count] - 1;

if(numOfDecimals > 1)
{
    // do something
}
```